# More reasonable to omit a random slope in (g)lmer?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am interested in an interaction between two factors, *group* and *condition*, each with two levels, on a continuous dependent variable measured ~100 times in each of 34 individuals, where each individual either belongs to group A or to group B, while condition is a within-subject variable. Usually, I would include a random slope for all fixed effects I am interested in (Bates et al., arXiv 2018):

"For the assessment of the significance of the experimental manipulation, it is therefore
essential to examine its fixed effect in the presence of the corresponding random slopes (see, e.g., Pinheiro and Bates (2000),Baayen (2008))."

The one grouping variable in my design is *individual*. The factor *group* is a between-subject (-individual) variable, so a random slope for *group* per individual is, of course, not possible. However, I could include a random slope for *condition*.
But:
I am wondering whether including a random slope for condition per individual is really a good idea, given that individuals are uniquely associated with *group* (a given individual belongs only to one group). If I include a random slope per condition, i.e., the condition effect can vary across subjects, does that not weaken the effect of group (which is also a between-individual factor, like *individual* itself)? That is, would inter-individual differences in the effect of *condition* that are due to different individuals belonging to different *group*'s not be treated as "idiosyncratic", individual- (rather than group-) specific effects?

Thanks very much for your help.